# Unable to play movies at all

Tags: 12.10, video, video-player, codecs

I just installed Ubuntu, and thus I'm unable to play movies. For example, if I run *.mkv file, I get the error of " `Gstreamer backend error - Can't play the text file without video or visualization`". If I run *.avi one, it says " `Gstreamer backend error -Your Gstream installation is missing a plugin`"

What should I install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install codecs.

Either you install vlc, this will intern download all codecs or install `Ubuntu restricted extras` from software center.